# API Domain | How to get domain in hubspot, then pass it to api calls before axios calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, hubspot

I want to get the domain name after axios calls are made. Because the axios calls need the domain URL to make them work.

The API call is static I tried to place my domain URL and the calls works fine. We plan to make our theme installed to another domain so my code will definitely won't work :(.  So I need to make it dynamic so the code will work on any domain to be installed.

Here's the code below I tried to run but I can't get any working results :(

```
const axios = require("axios"); 

exports.main = async (context, sendResponse) => {
  // Use axios to make a GET request to the search API 
  const config = {
    method: "get",
    url: `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/${context.contact.vid}/associations/deals`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer pat-na1-1d1c158f-6f71-4669-b3e9-0d0fa47b89b2",
    },
  }; 
  try {
    
    const host = window.location.hostname;
    
    const deals = [];
    const { data: dealIds } = await axios(config);   
    for await (const dealId of dealIds.results) {
      const { data: deal } = await axios.get(
        `${"https://" + host }/_hcms/api/congratsdeal_new?id=${dealId.id}`
      );
      deals.push(deal);
    }
    sendResponse({ statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(deals) });
  } catch (error) {
    sendResponse({ statusCode: 400, body: JSON.stringify(error) });
  }
};
```

I want to make API calls work when installed to another domains. to make it dynamic because what if non coder will install the theme and won't be able to replace the static url we placed to the JS file just to make it work and It's not good :(

Comment: Why are you not using a _relative_ URL then? (Is that because you need to ensure HTTPS is used, even if the site it gets used on uses just HTTP? Because I can hardly think of a proper reason besides maybe that.)

Comment: _"Here's the code below I tried to run but I can't get any working results"_ - that is hardly a proper problem description, that we could do much with. What currently happens with the code as shown then? Do you get any JS errors? Is the request being made to a wrong URL? ...?

Answer (score 0):

To make the API calls in your code work when installed on different domains without hardcoding the domain URL, you can modify your code as follows:

Pass the API base URL as a parameter: Instead of hardcoding the API base URL, you can pass it as a parameter to your main function. This way, you can configure the API base URL when your code is installed on different domains.

Use relative URLs for API endpoints: Instead of constructing the full URL including the domain for each API endpoint, use relative URLs for your API endpoints. Axios will automatically resolve these relative URLs relative to the base URL you provide.

Here's the modified code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

exports.main = async (context, sendResponse, apiBaseUrl) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      method: "get",
      url: `/crm/v3/objects/contacts/${context.contact.vid}/associations/deals`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer pat-na1-1d1c158f-6f71-4669-b3e9-0d0fa47b89b2",
      },
    };

    const deals = [];
    const { data: dealIds } = await axios(config);

    for await (const dealId of dealIds.results) {
      const { data: deal } = await axios.get(
        `${apiBaseUrl}/_hcms/api/congratsdeal_new?id=${dealId.id}`
      );
      deals.push(deal);
    }
    
    sendResponse({ statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(deals) });
  } catch (error) {
    sendResponse({ statusCode: 400, body: JSON.stringify(error) });
  }
};
```

Now, when you call the main function, pass the API base URL as a parameter:

```js
const apiBaseUrl = "https://api.hubapi.com"; // Change this to the actual base URL
exports.main(context, sendResponse, apiBaseUrl);
```

By doing this, you can configure the apiBaseUrl dynamically based on the domain where your code is installed, making your code work on different domains without the need for hardcoded URLs in your JavaScript file.

Comment: Hello sir. Appreciate the response. I tried to used your modified code above and still the display is not working

Comment: Hello sir is it working on another account and different domains ? On my account I have 4 domains and it works even 1 domain is being used. but im afraid it won't work on another hubspot account to be this theme to installed.